# How to save a variable with local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, timer, local-storage

I have created a timer with javascript which is started when the user begins a game, and stops when the game is completed. I would like to be able to record the users best time and save it using local storage. The code below shows my function which is fired on completion of the game, and works as far as displaying the user's best time on the page, however local storage is not retaining the variable, userBestTime, after the page is reloaded. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function stop() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = false;
    $(stopwatchEl).addClass('endgame');
    let timeTaken = stopwatchEl.textContent;
    let timeInMs = ((Number(timeTaken.split(':')[0])*60000) + 
                    (Number(timeTaken.split(':')[1])*1000) + 
                    (Number(timeTaken.split(':')[2]))); 
    let bestTime = 9999999;
    if (timeInMs < bestTime) {
        bestTime = timeTaken;
    }        
    localStorage.setItem('bestTime', JSON.stringify(bestTime));
    let jsonString = localStorage.getItem('bestTime');
    let userBestTime = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    $('.best-time').html('Best Time: ' + userBestTime);
    console.log(userBestTime);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the expected result?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: The time the user has taken to complete the game is stored in the variable, userBestTime, and displayed on the screen. I would like this variable to be saved in local storage so that it remains on the screen after the user has reloaded the page

Comment: To sum up: you run your code, nothing happens and don't know where to look at. Start by finding your browser's developer tools (typically mapped with F12). There're two basic tools that help here: an "Storage" or similarly named tab where you can inspect the contents of local storage and a "Debugger", "Sources" or something like that where you see the JavaScript code and can click on the margin to make the execution stop and check variables line by line.